# Date comparison on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get specific total amount on query but it needs to be compared on two dates, Due Date and Payment Date. I already do some query but I always found problem when comparing Payment Date and Due Dates.

```
SELECT ContractID, DueDate, PaymentDate, OutstandingBalance [Outstanding], MonthlyAmortization, 
row_number() over(partition by ContractID order by DueDate desc) as rn 
FROM [div].[ClientsLedger] 
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/31/2023' AND PaymentDate IS NOT NULL AND ContractID = 156
```

Here is the result of first query with late payment, I want to get rid of the first row because it is late as of December and retain the rest of the result.

[image]

```
SELECT ContractID, DueDate, PaymentDate, OutstandingBalance [Outstanding], MonthlyAmortization, 
row_number() over(partition by ContractID order by DueDate desc) as rn 
FROM [div].[ClientsLedger] 
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/31/2023' AND PaymentDate IS NOT NULL AND ContractID = 2254
```

This is the expected result when there is no late payment.

[image]

I already solved the issue thanks for the help, I created a query where the first result is separated to perform the comparison and combine with the rest of the result.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ContractID, DueDate, 
CASE 
WHEN DueDate >= PaymentDate THEN PaymentDate
ELSE NULL
END AS PaymentDate,
OutstandingBalance [Outstanding], MonthlyAmortization, 
row_number() over(partition by ContractID order by DueDate desc) as rn 
FROM [div].[ClientsLedger] 
WHERE 
DueDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/31/2023' 
AND PaymentDate IS NOT NULL
AND ContractID = 156
UNION ALL
SELECT ContractID, DueDate, PaymentDate, OutstandingBalance [Outstanding], MonthlyAmortization, row_number() over(partition by ContractID order by DueDate desc) as rn FROM [div].[ClientsLedger]
WHERE 
DueDate BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND DATEADD(MONTH, -2, '1/31/2023')
AND PaymentDate IS NOT NULL
AND ContractID = 156
```

Comment: Those are strings, not dates. In less than 5% of the world those strings could be cast to dates, anywhere else they'd result either in a cast error or a string comparison that returned nothing. Use proper date-typed fields and proper, date-typed parameters instead. If you absolutely have to, use the unambiguous, unseparated date format *for the comparison values only*, ie ` DueDate BETWEEN '20000101' and '20230131'`. Any other string will get converted based on the server's locale settings

Comment: Post the table schema, test data and expected results as *text* in the question itself, not images. Images can't be copied and tested.

Comment: You should also explain the logic you want to implement. The query you posted only selects past rows based on the date. It doesn't try to restrict them to late payments

Answer (score 0):

`'1/1/2000'` and `'1/31/2023'` are strings, not dates. If `DueDate` is also a string, `BETWEEN '1/1/2000' AND '1/31/2023'` will result in a string comparison using string ordering rules, which won't match anything. If `DueDate` is a `date` or `datetime`, the result will be a cast error in 95% of the world as SQL Server tries to cast that *string* into a date before comparing it to the actual date values.

The real solution is to use a suitable date type for `DueDate`, eg `date` or `datetime2` and use date-typed parameters to pass actual dates to the query. If you absolutely have to, use the unambiguous, unseparated date format *for the comparison values only*, ie  `DueDate BETWEEN '20000101' and '20230131'`. Any other string will get converted based on the server's locale settings:

```
declare @from date='20000101', @to date='20230131'

SELECT ...
FROM [div].[ClientsLedger] 
WHERE DueDate BETWEEN @from AND @to ...
```

If the field type is `date`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` you can also use the ISO8601 format, `YYYY-MM-DD`. The legacy `datetime` type will treat this as a localized string though. If you have to hard-code a date value, it's safer to use `YYYYMMDD`

**Calculate the dates on the fly**

Another option is to calculate the end date on the fly. It seems that the start date is a fixed date in the past, while the end date is the end of the past month. You can use calculate this on the fly with [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
declare @to date=EOMONTH(GetDate(),-1)
```

Comment: I already tried your solution, but still the same result. I want to get rid of late payment but if the first row is late payment only then retain the second to the last row. Also, data types that I use for Due Date and Payment Date is date only

Comment: @Mike post the table schema and sample data. There may not be any data in that period to begin with, or the other conditions eliminate all matches. Or `DueDate` may be a string instead of a date. One thing is certain, using a hard-coded US-style date literal won't work